# Obtener una coincidencia en un texto con expresiones regulares

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Estoy realizando una práctica en c# y me gustaría saber como puedo obtener una subcadena de una cadena que cumpla unos requisitos.

Por ejemplo, querría sacar de ahí lo que corresponda con una **IP** que sería `192.168.1.1`. Había pensado en expresiones regulares, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, ya que el siguiente código no me devuelve ningún valor.

```
 Regex ipV4 = new Regex(@"^\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
 string s = "naieofnai555aedae192.168.1.1andaiodane";
 Match match = ipV4.Match(s);            

 if (match.Success)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("IP was {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando `^` y `\b` en tu expresión y ninguno de los 2 se cumple.

- `^` coincide con el inicio del texto.
- `\b` coincide con un límite de palabra completa (este funcionaría si no hubiese letras, números o guiones bajos alrededor del IP).

Esto está explicado en [Delimitadores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions).

Además, estás utilizando `.Groups[1]`, pero eso se utiliza cuando hay paréntesis dentro de la expresión regular (esto está explicado en [El grupo capturado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/30wbz966(v=vs.110).aspx#the_captured_group)).

Si realmente te interesa extraer cualquier grupo de 4 dígitos separados por puntos, sólo es necesario eliminar esos delimitadores.

---

**Obtener sólo la primera coincidencia**

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
string ipv4 = @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}";
string s   = @"naieofnai555aedae192.168.1.1andaiodane";

Match m = Regex.Match(s, ipv4);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP encontrado: {0}", m.Value);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/NUfVeL

**Encontrar todas las coincidencias**

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
string ipv4 = @"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}";
string s    = @"naieofnai555aedae192.168.1.1andaiodane111.222.111.222ooooo";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, ipv4)) //bucle para obtener todas las coincidencias
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP encontrado: {0}", m.Value);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/dR00mt

---

**Alternativas para coincidir con una IP**

1. Se puede escribir más acotado (aunque no cambiaría la eficiencia):

   ```
   string ipv4 = @"\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}";
   ```
2. O sólo podrías permitir números entre 0 y 255 (para extraer cualquier IP).

   ```
   string ipv4 = @"(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}";
   ```

Comment: estaba bueno el cafe, bueno quizas demasiado flojo para usted. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto gracias! Y hay forma de que detecte IPv6 tambien?

Comment: La idea de esta respuesta es explicar el uso de expresiones regulares para encontrar una o todas las coincidencia en un string. Si tu intención es procesar una dirección de IP, recomendaría usar el método [IPAddress.TryParse(String, IPAddress)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esta validación:

```
Regex ip = new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}");
string input = "naieofnai555aedae192.168.1.1andaiodane";
MatchCollection result = ip.Matches(input);
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

Probando la respuesta de federhico con el primer caso si devolvió bien, pero el segundo no, porque el ip no está separado por espacios en el texto "input". O sea, funciona cuando "naieofnai555aedae 192.168.1.1 andaiodane". Explicación que da Mariano...

Answer (score -1):

Basado en [esta Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890789/regex-for-an-ip-address) , Te diría que pruebes con

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

o

```
Regex ip = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
MatchCollection result = ip.Matches(input);
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```